# Which verb to use with "pair of X"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Which of the following is correct:

1. Every pair of two different people **are** of different countries.
2. Every pair of two different people **is** of different countries.

Comment: Either is used by native speakers. Both are used by native speakers.

Comment: ... Though some would not like the sound of either.

Comment: A pair of people?

Comment: _Pair of two_ is tautological  (a pair means two).